# What is the meaning of mail in the CCPA (California Consumer Privacy Act of 2018)?

Tags: california, civil-law, data-protection, data-ownership, ccpa

The [CCPA](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa) states that under section [1798.130(2)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=1798.130.&lawCode=CIV) customers can request their data **BY_MAIL OR BY ELECTRONIC MEANS** as the **customer** chooses.

However NOWHERE on any website can I find a  button or form to demand information via physical mail and on top of that this is economically  infeasible for businesses that are small g     frm.

Is everyone non-compliant mr or am I getting something wrong?

**I am talking about ip logs mainly here.**

Comment: http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?division=3.&part=4.&lawCode=CIV&title=1.81.5
This extract may be relevant to others "A business shall be in violation of this title if it fails to cure any alleged violation within 30 days after being notified of alleged noncompliance. Any business, service provider, or other person that violates this title shall be subject to an injunction and liable for a civil penalty of not more than two thousand five hundred dollars ($2,500) for each violation or seven thousand five hundred dollars ($7,500) for each intentional violation..."

Comment: Is it illeagal to not provide such a button or form.

Comment: Please, please try to proofread your posts.  Use a spelling and grammar checker; there are plenty available.  It has so many typos that it's hard to read.  For example, I have no idea what "small g frm" or "non-compliant mr" mean.

Comment: Further, examples of supposedly non-compliant businesses might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misreading the law.  You need to keep reading the section you referenced (emphasis added):

> The disclosure...shall be made in writing and delivered through the consumer’s account with the business, if the consumer maintains an account with the business, or by mail or electronically at the consumer’s option **if the consumer does not maintain an account with the business**

Thus, the option to have the disclosure sent by mail only applies to consumers who do not have an account with the business.  Since presumably a large number of sites only maintain personal information for users with accounts, such sites need not provide a mail option.  Further, it doesn't say there needs to be a button: you just need the ability to say you'd like it mailed to you in the request somehow, and then they need to comply when you do.

Comment: However data like ip logs is never associated with any account.

Comment: Could please explain for example a website may have ip logs from millions of users g does that mean they must require to give in writing the response to a million users?Anyone will go bankrupt like this.

Comment: @astackexchangeuser IP logs alone, without accompanying profiles, would _likely_ not be personal information in many (but perhaps not all) cases.  See [Is an IP address considered “personal information” under the CCPA?](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/privacy-faqs-is-an-ip-address-75159/)

Comment: Thanks for that our website will anyway flush logs everyday.

Comment: I know I am extending this discussion too much but what if ip used for protection against DDOS.

Comment: @astackexchangeuser For a specific use-case like that, you'd really need a lawyer to examine _exactly_ how you're using it.  I wouldn't be comfortable answering based on a general description like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.If ip logs arn't they should (This is not legal advice and I am not a lawyer) not mainly be mainly because it is just searching logs for frequency of ip.

Comment: (This is not legal advice and I am not a lawyer)favaourably https://iapp.org/news/a/are-ip-addresses-personal-information-under-ccpa/.